# Query Owner field not working?

Tags: soql

the compiler doesn't like the owner.city... it's fine with owner.alias though. Why isn't this working? how do i fix it?

```
select Id, owner.street, owner.city From custom_object__c where owner.alias = 'Test'
```

Comment: Is it a typo you have alias = 'Test' while it has to be owner.alias = 'Test'?

Comment: Also can you please what the full error is. Does it say No such column 'city' on entity 'Name' If the error is on name you might be facing the polymorphic relation lash of salesforce mentioned here : http://www.tgerm.com/2010/11/no-such-column-on-entity-error.html check if your owner field is pointing to both user and queue when you look at the field from the UI.

Comment: You can't make custom objects be owned by a queue. I think the issue is that Salesforce doesn't expose any of the owner address fields. I tried and could get phone, and other fields, but none of the address fields.

Comment: Custom objects can be owned by queues (http://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/queues_overview.htm). It's weird that you can't pull user address information, though. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @rao thanks, that looks like the cause of the problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a definitive reason why you can't get to certain owner fields, but I just tested some queries and was able to get to most owner fields except for the address fields. For example, phone works, but street and city don't. This may have something to do with the polymorphic nature of owners. You could split the query into two or create a separate map of users to get the owner address information.