# Owner custom fields and some standard fields are not accessible in relations

Tags: apex, soql, permissions

I am trying to access owner information using soql for managed packaged sobject.

```
select id,ownerId,owner.name, owner.Email_Subscription__c from ARE__HavesWants__c
```

I tried above query but it is giving below error.

```
No such column 'Email_Subscription__c' on entity 'Name'
```

But when i removed owner.Email_Subscription__c it works, i.e. standard fields are accessible but custom fields are not accessible.

Is this any permission issue?
Please Help.

Comment: did you check the Field Level Security of the field Email_Subscription__c to see if your profile has access to it ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunately the Owner relation is a kind of strange.

Even if you prefix it the right way: it fails. This strange behavior seems not to be related to Managed Packages but the polymorphic nature of the Owner field. It was already noticed for **some** standard fields [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14822/query-owner-field-not-working).

**Background**

For Lead, Case, Knowledge article, Service contract and CustomObjects the Owner-field can not only be of type "User", but also of type "Group". Reason is, that the owner can also be a [queue](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=queues_overview.htm&language=en_US).

Like @PeterKnolle stated in the comment, in cases of such polymorphic foreign keys an SObject of type **[Name](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_name.htm)** will be used.

So all this applies **only**, if you select owners of Cases or CustomObject and **not** if you do the same query on e. g. Account.

So this works:

`SELECT Name, OwnerId, Owner.Name, Owner.Street FROM Account`

while this doesn't:

`SELECT Name, OwnerId, Owner.Name, Owner.Street FROM YourPrefix__YourObject__c`

Now if we recognize the polymorphism, what could be meaningful? I would expect to:

- either be able to access all fields of both possible objects-types (merged, keeping the non-existent columns NULLed for the records of the other type)
- or only those which are present in both (intersecting set of fields).

But the reality is different.

**Status Quo**

What I have tried so far, goes like this:

- works:

  - Owner.Name
  - Owner.Id
  - Owner.Type
  - Owner.Email
  - Owner.Username
  - Owner.LastName
  - Owner.FirstName
  - Owner.Title
  - Owner.Phone
  - Owner.Alias
  - Owner.UserRoleId
  - Owner.ProfileId
  - Owner.LastReferencedDate
  - Owner.Owner.LastViewedDate
- fails:

  - Owner.***AnyCustomField__c***
  - Owner.DeveloperName
  - Owner.RelatedId
  - Owner.OwnerId
  - Owner.DoesSendEmailToMembers
  - Owner.DoesIncludeBosses
  - Owner.CreatedDate
  - Owner.CreatedById
  - Owner.LastModifiedDate
  - Owner.LastModifiedById
  - Owner.SystemModstamp
  - Owner.CompanyName
  - Owner.Division
  - Owner.Department
  - Owner.Stree and all other Adress-Fields
  - Owner.Longitude and Latitude
  - Owner.StayInTouchNote
  - Owner.StayInTouchSignature
  - Owner.StayInTouchSubject
  - Owner.Signature
  - Owner.SenderName
  - Owner.SenderEmail
  - Owner.EmailPreferencesStayInTouchReminder
  - Owner.EmailPreferencesAutoBccStayInTouch
  - Owner.Fax
  - Owner.MobilePhone
  - Owner.CommunityNickname
  - Owner.Active
  - Owner.TimeZoneSidKey
  - Owner.LocaleSidKey
  - Owner.ReceivesInfoEmails
  - Owner.EmailEncodingKey
  - Owner.ReceivesAdminInfoEmails
  - Owner.OfflineTrialExpirationDate
  - Owner.LastPasswordChangeDate
  - Owner.LastLoginDate
  - Owner.ManagerId
  - Owner.DelegatedApproverId
  - Owner.EmployeeNumber
  - Owner.LanguageLocaleKey
  - Owne
  - Owner.DefaultGroupNotificationFrequency
  - Owner.DigestFrequency
  - Owner.SmallPhotoUrl
  - Owner.FullPhotoUrl
  - Owner.AboutMe
  - Owner.FederationIdentifier
  - Owner.Extension
  - Owner.CallCenterId
  - Owner.AccountId
  - Owner.ContactId
  - Owner.UserPreferencesHideS1BrowserUI
  - Owner.UserPreferencesShowCountryToGuestUsers
  - Owner.UserPreferencesShowPostalCodeToGuestUsers
  - Owner.UserPreferencesShowStateToGuestUsers
  - Owner.UserPreferencesShowCityToGuestUsers
  - Owner.UserPreferencesShowTitleToGuestUsers
  - Owner.UserPreferencesShowProfilePicToGuestUsers
  - Owner.UserPreferencesShowCountryToExternalUsers
  - Owner.UserPreferencesShowPostalCodeToExternalUsers
  - Owner.UserPreferencesShowStateToExternalUsers
  - Owner.UserPreferencesShowCityToExternalUsers
  - Owner.UserPreferencesShowStreetAddressToExternalUsers
  - Owner.UserPreferencesShowFaxToExternalUsers
  - Owner.UserPreferencesShowMobilePhoneToExternalUsers
  - Owner.UserPreferencesShowWorkPhoneToExternalUsers
  - Owner.UserPreferencesShowEmailToExternalUsers
  - Owner.UserPreferencesShowManagerToExternalUsers
  - Owner.UserPreferencesShowTitleToExternalUsers
  - Owner.UserPreferencesDisableFileShareNotificationsForApi
  - Owner.UserPreferencesEnableAutoSubForFeeds
  - Owner.UserPreferencesDisableSharePostEmail
  - Owner.UserPreferencesDisableBookmarkEmail
  - Owner.UserPreferencesOptOutOfTouch
  - Owner.UserPreferencesDisableMessageEmail
  - Owner.UserPreferencesDisableLikeEmail
  - Owner.UserPreferencesDisCommentAfterLikeEmail
  - Owner.UserPreferencesHideSecondChatterOnboardingSplash
  - Owner.UserPreferencesHideChatterOnboardingSplash
  - Owner.UserPreferencesHideCSNDesktopTask
  - Owner.UserPreferencesDisMentionsCommentEmail
  - Owner.UserPreferencesDisableMentionsPostEmail
  - Owner.UserPreferencesHideCSNGetChatterMobileTask
  - Owner.UserPreferencesApexPagesDeveloperMode
  - Owner.UserPreferencesContentEmailAsAndWhen
  - Owner.UserPreferencesContentNoEmail
  - Owner.UserPreferencesDisProfPostCommentEmail
  - Owner.UserPreferencesDisableLaterCommentEmail
  - Owner.UserPreferencesDisableChangeCommentEmail
  - Owner.UserPreferencesDisableProfilePostEmail
  - Owner.UserPreferencesDisableFollowersEmail
  - Owner.UserPreferencesDisableAllFeedsEmail
  - Owner.UserPreferencesReminderSoundOff
  - Owner.UserPreferencesTaskRemindersCheckboxDefault
  - Owner.UserPreferencesEventRemindersCheckboxDefault
  - Owner.UserPreferencesActivityRemindersPopup
  - Owner.ForecastEnabled
  - Owner.UserPermissionsChatterAnswersUser
  - Owner.UserPermissionsSiteforcePublisherUser
  - Owner.UserPermissionsSiteforceContributorUser
  - Owner.UserPermissionsSupportUser
  - Owner.UserPermissionsInteractionUser
  - Owner.UserPermissionsKnowledgeUser
  - Owner.UserPermissionsSFContentUser
  - Owner.UserPermissionsMobileUser
  - Owner.UserPermissionsCallCenterAutoLogin
  - Owner.UserPermissionsOfflineUser
  - Owner.UserPermissionsMarketingUser
  - Owner.OfflinePdaTrialExpirationDate

Comment: The fields that work should be those on the [Name object](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_name.htm).  The Owner field has [namePointing](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm) equal to true.

Comment: @PeterKnolle : YES that's it! Today I run into that issue while using my custom.query() function which does stuff like `SELECT *, Owner.*, CreatedBy.* FROM WhatEver` and I lost hours... I will update my answer. Thanks Peter!

Answer (score 3):

Since that question is still actual, i find helpful to share the way around i found for myself to filter records by Owner's custom field value.

My goal was to filter activities by owner's Primary Function which is a custom picklist field.

So i added a **custom formula field** named `Owner_Primary_Functions__c` to Activities object to represent the field value from related `User` objects for `Task` records. In my case the formula was `TEXT(Owner:User.Primary_Functions__c)`.

Now this query works for me:

```
SELECT Id, Subject, Owner.Name, Owner_Primary_Functions__c FROM Task
    WHERE Owner_Primary_Functions__c = :someFunction
```

Comment: Brilliant! This helped me immensely today!