# SOQL query to read Owner fields

Tags: soql, owner

I am trying to write a SOQL query to return some Lead data, along with the Lead Owner's CompanyName.

I have tried multiple iterations, but cannot seem to get the syntax right.

Something like this:

`[select Id, Name, OwnerId, (select Id, CompanyName from User where Id =: OwnerId) from Lead  limit 10]`

Answer (score 2):

When you need to traverse through a reference field, you can use a dot operator to get the related object's fields. In this case this would be `Owner.CompanyName` because this is a standard reference field.

Similarly lets say if this would have been a custom reference field called `Owner__c` on Lead; with the relationship name as Owner__r, syntax to get the reference field would have beeen `Owner__r.CompanyName`

The actual query would look like below-

> SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId, Owner.CompanyName From Lead LIMIT 10

The query you are trying to write is used to retrieve child object's records along with the record of current object.

Comment: It isn't necessarily a "parent", by the way, but just a referenced object using a Lookup field. This only is a "parent" for a Master Detail relationship.

Comment: @PhilW you're right, thanks for the correction, I have amended the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately not all Owner fields can be referenced via a dot operator.  CompanyName is one that cannot.  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47467/owner-custom-fields-and-some-standard-fields-are-not-accessible-in-relations